# Why is RemoveDirectory function not deleting the top most folder?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, win32-process

refer: codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=239271

When using the function below to delete folders, all folders, subfolders and files are getting deleted except for the top most folder. Say for the path `c:\folder1\folder2` every thing under `folder2` is deleted except for `folder2`.

```
BOOL DeleteDirectory(const TCHAR* sPath)  
{  
    HANDLE hFind; // file handle
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

    TCHAR DirPath[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR FileName[MAX_PATH];

    _tcscpy(DirPath,sPath);
    _tcscat(DirPath,_T("\\"));
    _tcscpy(FileName,sPath);
    _tcscat(FileName,_T("\\*")); // searching all files
    int nRet = 0;
    hFind = FindFirstFile(FileName, &FindFileData); // find the first file
    if( hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
    {
        do
        {
            if( IsDots(FindFileData.cFileName) ) 
                continue; //if not directory continue

            _tcscpy(FileName + _tcslen(DirPath), FindFileData.cFileName);
            if((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) 
            {
                // we have found a directory, recurse
                if( !DeleteDirectory(FileName) ) 
                    break;   // directory couldn't be deleted
            }
            else 
            {
                if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY)
                    _wchmod(FileName, _S_IWRITE); // change read-only file mode

                if( !DeleteFile(FileName) ) 
                    break;  // file couldn't be deleted
            }
        }while( FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) );

        nRet = FindClose(hFind); // closing file handle
    }

    return RemoveDirectory(sPath); // remove the empty (maybe not) directory and returns zero when RemoveDirectory function fails
}
```

Any help in finding the issue is appreciated.
During debugging I noticed that the `FindClose` function was successfully closing the file handle but `GetLastError` was returning 32 ("The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process") However I have no clue after trying with process explorer.

Comment: Call GetLastError immediately after DeleteFile failure and find out what error it gives. That should help you in resolving this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst you can delete a directory this way, it's simpler to let the system do it for you by calling [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) passing `FO_DELETE`. Remember that you must double null-terminate the string you pass to this API.

Comment: This function has been replaced in Windows Vista by IFileOperation. My application needs to support all windows versions above and including windows XP.

Comment: The function has not been replaced in Vista. The documentation is simply wrong. `SHFileOperation` works on Win2k, XP, Vista, 7. It will work on Windows 8. MS is not in the habit of removing functions. Once they are in they stay in.

Comment: I blindly trusted the MSDN documentation. Thank you David for your time.

Comment: What they mean is that new applications should prefer to use `IFileOperation` which has more capability. However, doing so makes it hard to support XP since you have to fall back on the older API. If you don't need the new functionality then it's just easier to use the old API.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to close the file handle before the recursive call.  Which means after exiting the recursive call you must again set your your file handle to something appropriate.

SHFileOperation may be a better solution; I am just answering the OP's question of why their code wasn't working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Refer:http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-337897.html
Given below is the code to delete directory using SHFileOperation

```
bool DeleteDirectory(LPCTSTR lpszDir, bool noRecycleBin = true)
{
    int len = _tcslen(lpszDir);
    TCHAR* pszFrom = new TCHAR[len+4]; //4 to handle wide char
    //_tcscpy(pszFrom, lpszDir); //todo:remove warning//;//convet wchar to char*
    wcscpy_s (pszFrom, len+2, lpszDir);
    pszFrom[len] = 0;
    pszFrom[len+1] = 0;

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileop;
    fileop.hwnd   = NULL;    // no status display
    fileop.wFunc  = FO_DELETE;  // delete operation
    fileop.pFrom  = pszFrom;  // source file name as double null terminated string
    fileop.pTo    = NULL;    // no destination needed
    fileop.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION|FOF_SILENT;  // do not prompt the user

    if(!noRecycleBin)
        fileop.fFlags |= FOF_ALLOWUNDO;

    fileop.fAnyOperationsAborted = FALSE;
    fileop.lpszProgressTitle     = NULL;
    fileop.hNameMappings         = NULL;

    int ret = SHFileOperation(&fileop); //SHFileOperation returns zero if successful; otherwise nonzero 
    delete [] pszFrom;  
    return (0 == ret);
}
```

Comment: This is a cut and paste from http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=239271 and I feel that you ought to acknowledge it as such.

Comment: sorry about that, i was in a hurry then, now i have added the acknowledgement.